# Can't figure out how to run my blackberry app in blackberry bold 9780 simulator

Tags: blackberry, simulator, bold

I’m trying to submit my fist blackberry app.  I wanted to fist test it on the black berry bold 9780.
I was able to install and run the emulator ok.  I loaded in my code file by going to file -> load application or them.  I loaded the file (LITTLE ANIMATION APPERED IN CENTYER OF SCREEN).  I press the right arrow key until all appeared with 6 icons under it for apps.  I did not see my app there.  I then tried favreit, which was empty. I could not fine my app anywise.  How do I run the app after I load it? 
Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a "downloads" folder. It should be in there.

Comment: Hi  The downloads folder is empty :(.  Thats where I thought it should be.

Comment: @ted sorry, I hoped it would be easy - I have not installed that sdk yet, still working on older 4.5 platform compatibility.

Comment: Hi,Yell I unistall and re-install the emulater, and yes, it did get put in the download folder.  So frustrating!!!!!!! Ted